# Can get any OUTLOOK conditionals to work at all - HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

My OUTLOOK conditionals are not working. The only one that works is the table width. but, I can't style anything else.

Below is my email HTML that I am trying to get it work. I can not figure it out?

```
    https://gist.github.com/castledoor/05c48bca2db5a67e649f20c95d8d25a6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could only find one Outlook conditional statement. I wrapped it in a style tag and it seems to display better in Litmus for Outlook 2013, 2016, Windows Mail 10.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<STYLE type=text/css>
  .logo_block {
    display: none !important;
  }
</STYLE>
<![endif]-->
```

Say hi to Vinny for me.

Good luck.

Comment: do you have any idea why, .. display: none works nothing else..like i cant add any other styles to any other elements and this dosnt work   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<STYLE type=text/css>
  .logo_block {
  
    height: 180px !important;
  }

 

</STYLE>
<![endif]-->

Comment: I tried adding `background: #ff0000;` and that worked fine. If Outlook ignores your style sheet, try inlining values as well. Outlook goes crazy for inlining styles. I also suggest using `height="180"` for the table over `style="height: 180px";`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `dislay:none` has only partial support in Outlook, so can't be relied on. You're better off hiding content from it using `<!--[if !mso]><!-- --> [hidden stuff here] <!--<![endif]-->`

Outlook also has terrible support for `div` tags. So i'd recommend removing them from the desktop version and applying your classes to the `td` instead. Then you probably won't need the conditional table on line 415.

Comment: thanks, yea i was been having some success removing the divs.. but still a ton of trouble, but at least its something..never thought it would be this hard.